# How to sort an array containing both characters and integers?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following array:

```
{5,"k",2,"d",3,"e"}
```

How can I sort the array such that the characters and integers are each grouped together and sorted:

```
{"d","e","k",2,3,5}
```

Comment: Implement your own `Comparator`, and call `Arrays.sort(arr, myComparator)`.

Comment: You should provide the code of your attempts so that we can help you improve them.

Comment: How did you declare the array?  Arrays generally cannot contain mutliple data types unless you are forcibly hacking them to do so.  The "code" you show is not valid Java, and your question is unclear.  Please clarify.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It smells of poor design IMHO. What I’m trying to say, think about your design again and your problem is likely to go away.

Comment: @JimGarrison I disagree that question is unclear. `arr` is likely an `Object[]`, though it could be a `Serializable[]` or `Comparable<?>[]`. Using a `Comparator<Object>` to sort the array, it makes no difference which of the three it is. The question clearly states the input values and the desired output, and simply asks how to accomplish that. That is clear enough, and 10 times better than most questions on here.

Comment: You are making assumptions about code that the OP has not provided.  While you may be right in this case, I've found often even the OP does not really know what the question is and needs prompting to understand what they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array by calling one of the `sort()` methods on [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

In your case, you'd want to call [`sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

Since your array is an `Object[]`, this means that you need to implement [`Comparator<Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Here is an *example* implementation that will sort your sample values as you want:

```
public final class MixedComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        Class<?> class1 = obj1.getClass();
        Class<?> class2 = obj2.getClass();

        // Sort values of same type according to their natural order
        if (class1 == class2)
            return ((Comparable)obj1).compareTo(obj2);

        // Sort values of different type by class name,
        // in descending order, so `String` sorts before `Integer`
        return class2.getName().compareTo(class1.getName());
    }
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
Object[] arr = { 5, "k", 2, "d", 3, "e" };
Arrays.sort(arr, new MixedComparator());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[d, e, k, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the proper output . Previously I had also implemented  the Comparator but not comparing class names .